# How to calculate explicitly the classical on-shell action for a harmonic oscillator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, action

So, short and sweet, I've been reading the path integrals book by Feynman and Hibbs, and one of the elementary problems they ask is to calculate the classical on-shell$^1$ action of a harmonic oscillator. I have some exposure in classical mechanics, but only the basics (until the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)) so could anyone resolve the calculations?

--

$^1$ The word *on-shell* means that the EL-eqs. are satisfied.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculating the action"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind the classical action of a system is the integral of Ldt where L is the lagrangian of the system. it satisfies the euler-lagrange equation.

Comment: @Siddharth'elMásGrande' ACuriousMind is well aware of what the action is. I don't have the book handy right now, but I'm pretty sure they wouldn't ask you to 'calculate' the action of a classical harmonic oscillator. Maybe you meant propagator, since the path integral is the focus of the text? Or are you asking how to discretise the action in the $e^{iS}$ to do the path integral?

Comment: Yes they would; see Shankar's Quantum Mechanics book, chapter 2, towards the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I randomly had this typed up in personal notes. Was probably an exercise somewhere.

Consider a harmonic oscillator, which is described by the Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2q^2$$
Doing the Legendre transform, we obtain the action as
$$\mathcal{S}=\tfrac{1}{2}m\int_0^t(\dot{q}^2-\omega^2q^2)dt'$$
Now we use the Euler-Lagrange equation to find the classical equation of motion:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}=-2\omega^2 q\quad \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}=2\dot{q}\quad \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}=2\ddot{q}$$
$$\ddot{q}_c=-\omega^2q_c$$
To solve this, we assume first that the solution will be something like $e^{\lambda t}$. We plug this into our differential equation
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{\lambda t}+\omega^2 e^{\lambda t}=\lambda^2 e^{\lambda t}+\omega^2 e^{\lambda t}=0$$
Factor out $e^{\lambda t}$ to obtain $\lambda^2+\omega^2=0$. This is solved by
$$\lambda=\pm i\omega$$
The general solution is the sum of the solutions created by the two roots:
$$q=c_1e^{-i\omega t}+c_2e^{i\omega t}$$
Apply Euler's identity:
$$q=c_1[\cos(\omega t)-i\sin(\omega t)]+c_2[\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)]$$
Regroup terms and define $A=c_1+c_2$ and $B=i(c_2-c_1)$.
So our differential equation is solved by 
$$q_c=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$$
From here:
$$\dot{q}_c=-A\omega\sin(\omega t)+B\omega\cos(\omega t)$$
$$\dot{q}_c^2=A^2\omega^2\sin^2(\omega t)-2AB\omega^2\cos(\omega t)\sin(\omega t)+B^2\omega^2\cos^2(\omega t)$$
$$\omega^2q^2_c=\omega^2[A^2\cos^2(\omega t)+2AB\cos(\omega t)\sin(\omega t)+B^2\sin^2(\omega t)]$$
We use 
$$2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)$$
$$\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$$
Now the difference is 
$$\dot{q}_c^2-\omega^2q_c^2=-2AB\omega^2\sin(2\omega t)+(B^2-A^2)\omega^2\cos(2\omega t)$$
The antiderivative of the first part is
$$-2AB\omega^2\int\sin(2\omega t)dt=AB\omega\cos(2\omega t)$$
And the second part is
$$(B^2-A^2)\omega^2\int\cos(2\omega t)dt=\tfrac{1}{2}(B^2-A^2)\omega\sin(2\omega t)$$
We write the double angle cosine formula as 
$$\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$$
So our first part is 
$$AB\omega\cos(2\omega t)=AB\omega-2AB\omega\sin^2(\omega t)$$
Now that we have our antiderivative, we can calculate the action:
$$\tfrac{1}{2}m\int_0^t(\dot{q}^2-\omega^2q^2)dt'=\tfrac{1}{2}m\omega\left[(B^2-A^2)\sin(\omega t')\cos(\omega t')+AB-2AB\sin^2(\omega t')\right]_0^t$$
$$=\tfrac{1}{2}m\omega[(B^2-A^2)\sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)-2AB
\sin^2(\omega t)]$$
What are $A$ and $B$? We set $q_c(0)=q_I=A$. We solve
$$q_c(t)=q_F=q_I\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$$
for $B$:
$$B=\frac{q_F-q_I\cos(\omega t)}{\sin(\omega t)}$$
We plug this into the action, first we do $AB$,
$$AB=q_I\frac{q_F-q_I\cos(\omega t)}{\sin(\omega t)}$$
then $B^2-A^2$
$$B^2-A^2=\left(\frac{q_F-q_I\cos(\omega t)}{\sin(\omega t)}\right)^2-q_I^2=\frac{q_F^2-2q_Fq_I\cos(\omega t)+q_I^2\cos^2(\omega t)-q_I^2\sin^2(\omega t)}{\sin^2(\omega t)}$$
So 
$$-2AB\sin^2(\omega t)=\frac{-2q_Iq_F\sin^2(\omega t)+2q_I^2\cos(\omega t)\sin^2(\omega t)}{\sin(\omega t)}$$
And
$$(B^2-A^2)\cos(\omega t)\sin(\omega t)=\frac{q_F^2\cos(\omega t)-2q_Fq_I\cos^2(\omega t)+q_I^2\cos^3(\omega t)-q_I^2\sin^2(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)}{\sin(\omega t)}$$
We then use some more trig and rewrite 
$$q_I^2\cos^3(\omega t)=q_I^2\cos(\omega t)(1-\sin^2(\omega t))=q_I^2\cos(\omega t)-q_I^2\cos(\omega t)\sin^2(\omega t)$$
Now we add the two parts together:
$$(B^2-A^2)\cos(\omega t)\sin(\omega t)-2AB\sin^2(\omega t)=\frac{q_F^2\cos(\omega t)+q_I^2\cos(\omega t)-2q_Iq_F\sin^2(\omega t)-2q_Fq_I\cos^2(\omega t)}{\sin(\omega t)}$$
This can of course be simplified to
$$\csc(\omega t)[(q_I^2+q_F^2)\cos(\omega t)-2q_Iq_F]$$
We finally conclude that the classical action is
$$\mathcal{S}[q_c]=\tfrac{1}{2}m\omega\csc(\omega t)[(q_I^2+q_F^2)\cos(\omega t)-2q_Iq_F]$$

Comment: brilliant answer! very informative, contained the exact information i was looking for! stackexchange is awesome :)

btw, you missed a factor of \omega^2 while taking the difference of \dot{q_c} and \omega ^2 q_c. otherwise, perfect answer. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The action $S$ is defined as the time integral of the Lagrangian $L$ of the system, and in classical mechanics the Lagrangian is just kinetic energy $T$ minus potential energy $V$. So the action can be written as follows:

$$S(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\dot x}) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \text{d}t \; [T(\mathbf{\dot x}) - V(\mathbf{x})]$$

For a harmonic oscillator with mass $m$ and frequency $\omega$, the kinetic energy as a function of velocity $\mathbf{\dot x}$ is $T(\mathbf{\dot x}) = \frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{\dot x}^2$, and the potential energy as a function of position $\mathbf{x}$ is $V(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\mathbf{x}^2$, so we get:

$$ S(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\dot x}) = \frac{1}{2}m \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \text{d}t \; \big[\mathbf{\dot x}^2 - \omega^2\mathbf{x}^2\big] $$

This is the action of the harmonic oscillator. The physical path $\mathbf{x}(t)$ that the harmonic oscillator will follow, is the path that minimizes the action (or in general, the path that produces a stationary point in the action); and solving this minimization problem (or in general, extremization problem) is equivalent to solving the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Lagrangian $L = T-V$.